# How can I make line chart of MPAndroidChart shows only fixed number of values at a time for example 5

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, mpandroidchart

I get a lot of values to plot on the chart but what I want is it shows only few values at a time and then the user is able to scroll horizontally but it shows fix a number of values on the screen that easy easily fix on screen
This is the result I'm getting
[image]

with this code snippet

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
private fun initChart() {

    lineDataSet?.let {
        it.setDrawHighlightIndicators(false)
        it.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER
        it.lineWidth = 2F
        it.circleRadius = 4F
        it.setDrawCircles(true)
        it.setDrawCircleHole(false)
        it.color = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.light_blue)
        it.setCircleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.light_blue))
    }
    iLineDataSet?.add(lineDataSet!!)
    lineData = LineData(iLineDataSet)
    lineData?.setDrawValues(false)
    chart.data = lineData

    val description = Description()
    description.isEnabled = false
    chart.description = description
    chart.isDragEnabled = true
    chart.setScaleEnabled(false)
    chart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
    chart.axisLeft.isEnabled = true
    chart.xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
    chart.axisLeft.setDrawGridLines(false)
    chart.axisRight.setDrawGridLines(false)
    chart.isHighlightPerTapEnabled = true
    chart.setDrawGridBackground(false)
    chart.setDrawBorders(false)
    chart.setBorderColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)

    chart.xAxis.setLabelCount(entryList.size, true)

    if (entryList[0].x != 0F) {
        chart.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0.5F
    } else {
        chart.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0F
    }

    chart.xAxis.axisMaximum = (entryList[entryList.lastIndex].x + 0.5F)

    chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10F)
    chart.xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
    chart.xAxis.valueFormatter = object : IndexAxisValueFormatter() {
        override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            calendar.timeInMillis = value.toLong()
            return "$value"
        }
    }
    chart.setNoDataText("No data")
    chart.setBorderWidth(2F)
    chart.invalidate()
}
```

Please help
Thanks :)

Comment: try `setMaxVisibleValueCount(count)` on xAxis

Comment: @Hababa Im using that bit its now working

Comment: Okay, it will be nice if you can update your post :)

Comment: @Hababa oh sorry I didn't use that attribute and I think I'm using I just added it and now it is working fine
Thanks, Man
Really appreciate for your time
You made my day

Comment: That's fine, glad to help you :)

Comment: @Hababa last one that when I get a lot of values form server it shows me values from the start
I want it takes me to the end of the chart
not from start
do you know about that

Comment: maybe `chart.centerViewTo(x, y, axis)` can do that you want -> you can move viewport  to end when new data set in.

Comment: There is one more way to achieve that: ```axisLeft.setLabelCount(3, true)``` - ```3``` represents the desired number of the visible labels, ```true``` means you put this number by force.